Safeeyes does not run in Ubuntu 24.04
I installed safeeyes on Ubuntu 24.04, and it does not work.
When I run it form the command line, I get the following error.
$ safeeyes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/safeeyes", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('safeeyes==2.1.5', 'console_scripts', 'safeeyes')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/safeeyes", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 205, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/safeeyes/__main__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from safeeyes import utility
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/safeeyes/utility.py", line 24, in <module>
    import imp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'

How to fix it?

The version of safeeyes shipped with Ubuntu 24.04 is not compatible with python3.12, the default python version of Ubuntu 24.04.
The simplest solution is to use the Official Safe Eyes PPA, which hosts a patched and updated version:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:safeeyes-team/safeeyes
sudo apt update
sudo apt install safeeyes


Alternative approach:
If you don't want to use the PPA, you can manually apply the patch from upstream. Run sudo nano /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/safeeyes/utility.py.
Comment out (or remove) line 24, import imp
Then, replace line 357 (imp.find_module(module)) with importlib.util.find_spec(module).
Now safeeyes should work normally.
