How to open a single app in a particular language while the system language is English?
I am a developer of Safe Eyes (an app that reminds you to blink eyes to prevent eye strain), and someone requested a feature that they want to open the app in Spanish, while the system language for all other apps is set to be English.
The app has already been translated to many languages, and would change its language if the system language is changed to Spanish.
When the Spanish language pack is already installed, is there any way the app can be launched in a Spanish while the system language is still English? Maybe with some environment variable while running the app?

In case you need to test the app to provide an answer, you can use the official PPA in Ubuntu 24.04 (or use the package from official repositories on previous versions of Ubuntu), as the official repository version in broken in 24.04:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:safeeyes-team/safeeyes

And sudo apt install safeeyes

Using LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 gnome-clocks and LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 gnome-calendar in an Arch Linux system:  https://i.sstatic.net/fzE1OSk6.png

@user68186 That is a known issue (https://askubuntu.com/q/1511628/124466). Solution is to use the updated version from the official PPA. It does not work with Ubuntu 24.04 because the previous version did not work with python3.12, and the new version did not get in before Ubuntu's package freeze

LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 safeeyes works in Arch after enabling the spanish locale . Let me test it in ubuntu. Please write that as an answer and I will accept it

I just verified that it works in Kubuntu 24.04

Enable Spanish Locale
Go to Settings > System > Region and Languages > Manage Installed Language > Install / Remove Languages. Select Spanish.

Use the LANG Variable to start Safe Eyes from the terminal:
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 safeeyes

The configuration should now be in Spanish:

The breaks should also be in Spanish:

Make Spanish the default
Open the app called Startup Applications and look for Safe Eyes:

Select Safe Eyes from the left panel and Click on the Edit button on the right. Add LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 to the Command section before safeeyes as shown below:

Save and close the app. Logout and log back in to automatically start Safe Eyes in Spanish.
Hope this helps

I noticed that. Thanks again

Here is the translation link https://hosted.weblate.org/projects/safe-eyes/-/bn/
